# Simple MATLAB Graph Plotting

Tags: matlab

This may be an obviously simple question, but i'm not sure how to do this.

I have 4 calculated values stored in 4 variables, each representing a condition. I want to simply display each of these in a graph with the condition/variable on the X axis and the values on the Y axis. I have tried the code below, but it just gives me a blank figure with values but no line.

```
figure(1)
T = TA;
S = SA;
U = UA;
O = OA;
plot(T,S,U,O, '--o')
shg
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try creating a Y variable to plot each variable against, then use the syntax `plot(T,Y,'r',S,Y,'b',U,Y,'k',...)`

Comment: Are your variables `T`, `S` etc scalars?

Comment: Yes, so for simplicity purposes.. T = 2, S = 4 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
figure(1)
T = 12;
S = 7;
U = 5;
O = 10;
plot([T,S,U,O], '--o');
set(gca,'XTick',[1,2,3,4]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'T','S','U','O'})
shg
```

for me this gave

[image]

Comment: Just what I needed thanks! But at the moment, along the X axis it goes.. T S U O T S U and without the last line it reads 1.. 1.5..2..2.5 etc . So for example it is plotting 7 (S) on the Y against 2 (the third value) on the X, but with the last line of code, it means the 7 is aligned with U instead of S.

Comment: I have `S` as second point, so I plotted it against `2` and labelled `2` with `S`. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I didn't see the edit you made. It works perfectly now. I also found that to do it for a Bar chart it is the same code but without the 'XTick' line. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check matlab help on plot and specifically linespecs to define the format you would like the data plotted in. For example, code below plots each variable in different color with line and symbol.

```
 figure;
 hold on;
 plot(T,'-bo');
 plot(S,'-g.');
 plot(U,'-rd');
 plot(O,'-mx');
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that and again the problem is I don't get any lines on the output. I've tried plotting X and Y, which gives me the Y values I want, but not what I want on the X axis (the variable names).  
    X = T; S, U, O;
    Y = 1:8;
    plot(X, Y)

Comment: OK, I didn't quite understand your question then. If you would like to label X axis, you can use xlabel('String to label x axis'); (see help for it).